# Laravel route is bringing me somewhere else

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to create CRUD app by Laravel and vue.js but here is always problem. When I run the app it goes to the dashboard and CRUD operations don't appear.
Here is the Routes/web.app codes below:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Inertia\Inertia;
use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
Route::get('/', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Welcome', [
        'canLogin' => Route::has('login'),
        'canRegister' => Route::has('register'),
        'laravelVersion' => Application::VERSION,
        'phpVersion' => PHP_VERSION,
    ]);
});
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';

Route::resource('Posts', PostController::class);
```

Comment: Can you please add your vue.js past?

Comment: @shaedrich which file you want?

Comment: the one with the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the point, you will be loggin before, so when you try to run your app,  it will take you to the dashboard.

**Solution:**
you should make sure that you have cleared all you caches/sessions data, then run **php artisan serve**,

Hopefully, now it will take you to / => the welcome page!

(If not) You have to see these things:

1. Your controller is not protected with any middleware(in the construct method).
2. You are not logged in as an authenticated your, try this in google chrome incognito mode. If http://localhost:8000 show your welcome page, then go to http://localhost:8000/posts route(first change Route::resource('Posts', PostController::class); with Route::resource('/posts', PostController::class);)
3. run **php artisan optimize:clear**