# Why the laravel crud goes to dashboard?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, crud

I am trying to create a crud app with laravel 9 and vuejs but when I run the app it goes to the dashboard and the crud operations don't appear. I want it to directly goes to the crud operations. Here is the web.app route codes:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Inertia\Inertia;
use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
Route::get('/', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Welcome', [
        'canLogin' => Route::has('login'),
        'canRegister' => Route::has('register'),
        'laravelVersion' => Application::VERSION,
        'phpVersion' => PHP_VERSION,
    ]);
});
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';

Route::resource('posts', PostController::class);
```

Comment: Where are your CRUD routes in this? Are they the `Route::resource('posts')` bit?

Comment: Please don't duplicate questions just because it doesn't get any answers. [Laravel route is bringing me somewhere else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73763037/laravel-route-is-bringing-me-somewhere-else)

Comment: @ceejayoz yes they are

Comment: @Peppermintology But I need the answer

Comment: Well, if your CRUD routes are at `/posts`, you're not going to see them at `/`. If you want the user to go straight to the `/posts` routes, you should set up the `/` route to be a redirect. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/redirects

Comment: I'm sure you do, but that's no reason to duplicate questions. If you've not received any answers, consider either editing your question or deleting it and creating a new question but altering how you ask the question and/or providing more detail.

Answer (score 0):

The Route::resource function creates the routes for you with defined paths shown in the link here:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller

If you want to define the endpoint for going directly to posts but want to keep the rest of the default resources you can do something like this:

```
Route::resource('posts',PostController::class)->except(['index']);

Route::get('/dashboard',[PostController::class,'index'])->name('dashboard');
```

And comment out the other Dashboard link

IF you want to change the home link, you can open the RouteServiceProvider in App/Providers/RouteServiceProvider and update it there to "/posts" which would be much faster and less confusing.

```
    public const HOME = '/posts';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated the App/Providers/RouteServiceProvider but still it goes to dashboard. Any suggestionS?

Comment: Make sure to clear your cache once done.
```php artisan cache:clear

php artisan route:cache```

Comment: Should I make any changes on web.app?

Comment: You dont need too if you go the RouteServiceProvider route

Comment: I cleared the caches and still same thing :(